# Estou aprendendo JS e estava testando functions e tenho uma duvida

Tags: javascript, funções, variáveis

Estava testando *function* e quis fazer que ele detectasse ! de uma mensagem:

```
//Detector de !
function detector(){
    var detector = txt.indexOf("!")
    if(detector>-1)
        return true
}
//reponder a mensagem
function msg(){
    if(detector()==true){
        return "true"
    }else{
        return "false"
    }
}
```

e tive ideia de criar uma function que executasse os dois:

```
function messenger(txt){
    detector();
    return msg();
}
```

coloco *function([mensagem])* e deveria responder true ou false mas n funcionou,ent pensei que fosse algum erro de sintaxe algo tipo:

```
function messenger(x){
    var txt = x 
    console.log(detector())
    console.log(msg())
}
```

coloquei *console.log* para ver se estava funcionando as *function*, aparentemente ss, mas a *var txt* nao estava funcionando ,so funciona quando eu declaro a variavel fora:

```
var txt = "!teste"
messenger()
```

Queria saber por que nao funciona quando coloco *function("!teste")* e se tem um jeito de fazer fucionar.
Agradeco :>

Comment: javascript usa contexto léxico, a variável txt tem que existir no momento que vc declara a função detector... acho que a melhor abordagem aí é enviar o txt como argumento da função detector

Comment: @guijob mas o txt do `messenger(txt)` nao eh considerado uma variavel?

Comment: sim, mas onde vc define a função é que conta, não onde vc chama.. no messenser vc chama a função detector... o javascript vai procurar o txt no contexto de onde vc definiu a função e não no contexto que você chamou ela

Comment: @guijob ah entendi vlw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não faz sentido a existência do algoritmo da função `messenger()`.

- `messenger()` é dependente da variável externa `txt`.
- O primeiro uso da função `detector()` é inócuo não afetando de forma alguma o fluxo de dados.
- A função `msg()` faz um uso mais racional da função `detector()` e só esse deveria ser mantido.

É melhor trabalhar os algoritmos já existentes do que criar algo novo baseado numa coleção de problemas.

Analisando a função detector:

```
function detector(){
    var detector = txt.indexOf("!")
    if(detector>-1)
        return true
}
```

A primeira mudança será a criação de um parâmetro `texto` tornando a função independente de variável externa:

```
function detector(texto){
    var detector = texto.indexOf("!")
    if(detector>-1)
        return true
}
```

Olhando com atenção a sentença:

```
if(detector>-1)
     return true
```

É uma redundância aliada a uma indefinição. Essa sentença diz que se retorne verdadeiro caso a variável `detector` seja verdadeira, mas se não for verdadeira o retorno é indefinido. Então para remover a redundância junto da indefinição apenas fazemos:

```
function detector(){
    var detector = txt.indexOf("!")
    return detector  > -1; //Sempre sera retornado o valor da comparação independente de teste prévio.
}
```

Falando em redundância você declarou uma variável com o mesmo nome da função e isso é um equivoco grave pois o impede de realizar [recursões](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) e [correcursões](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corecursion). Então cabe a simplificação:

```
function detector(texto) {
  return texto.indexOf("!") > -1;
}
```

O mesmo vale para a função `msg()` é possivel romper com a dependência de variáveis externas:

```
function msg(texto){
    if(detector(texto)==true){
        return "true"
    }else{
        return "false"
    }
}
```

Ao mesmo tempo que se remove as redundâncias, e para isso usei o método nativo [`Boolean.prototype.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean/toString) que retorna uma string representando o objeto Boolean específico:

```
function msg(texto) {
  return detector(texto).toString();
}
```

Juntando tudo que foi dito:

```js
//Detector de !
function detector(texto) {
  return texto.indexOf("!") > -1;
}

//reponder a mensagem
function msg(texto) {
  return detector(texto).toString();
}

console.log(msg("teste 1 !"));
console.log(msg("teste 2  "));
```

Sem a necessidade de uma terceira função.

Answer (score 0):

Quando você define a função detector:

```
function detector(){
    var detector = txt.indexOf("!")
    if(detector>-1)
        return true
}
```

o txt já tem que existir no escopo dessa função. Onde você vai chamar essa função não importa pro Javascript, o que importa é onde você define.

Então, você pode criar a variável num "escopo-pai" (nem sei se existe essa palavra):

```
var txt = "";
function detector(){
    var detector = txt.indexOf("!")
    if(detector>-1)
        return true
}
```

Ou definir nos parametros da função e enviar seu valor como argumento ao chamar a função:

```
function detector(txt){
    var detector = txt.indexOf("!")
    if(detector>-1)
        return true
}
```

É assim que o javascript funciona, e isso se chama **escopo léxico**.